# Trying to enable hardware virtualization in BIOS, but POWER SURGE DETECTED and BIOS reset. ASUS Z97-E

Tags: bios, desktop-computer, hardware-virtualization

I just bought this computer with **ASUS Z97-E motherboard and Intel i7 4790k**. I really would like to enable hardware virtualization so I can use install 64-bit OS as my guest machine.

The problem is, **every time when I turn on virtualization in BIOS settings, save and exit. The machine will shutdown. LEDs flash for a few times and the machine boots up with information "power surge detected, press F1 to enter settings".** It seems like the C.P.R is automatically invoked.

**UPDATE**: I guess it has nothing to do with power surge. I tried to disable the power surge detection in BIOS, and made sure it is disabled. Then I restart my computer with VT-x set, it still automatically shutdown, turn-on for half second, shutdown again, turn-on and flash, shutdown again(repeating this for several times), then the power came on asking me to enter BIOS setting and I can see the settings are reset back to default with no VT-x and power-surge detection on again. Is this the problem of motherboard, or CPU? Only this option(VT-x) is troublesome.

Is there anyone having this issue? What could be the possible cause? CPU? Motherboard? Power supply?

Comment: Hardware virtualization is not required for any 64-bit OS.

Comment: @Daniel B, He said "guest machine", and that's indeed a requirement for VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt

Comment: @Yang Du, sounds like a UEFI bug. What's the version of your UEFI ("BIOS")? There is an update in Jan 2016 (Version 0802): https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z97E/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: @TomYan Guess I missed that. // From my experience, it’s normal that the system completely shuts down when making settings changes like that. Of course, it’s a mystery why VT-x being disabled is the default.

Comment: @TomYan Thanks Tom. I tried this but with no luck. This is really weird as I can tune any other options in BIOS except for VT-x. There was only once that I successfully enabled VT-x and the BIOS doesn't reset. But after that the BIOS hangs on the logo screen and I cannot input anything to enter the BIOS settings. I was thinking about returning the parts but magically when I unplug the hard disk and plug again the system boots up. Seems like maybe some of my parts are defective, maybe motherboard but I am not so sure. Any suggestions? Should I buy a new motherboard as the last resort?

Comment: I'm also thinking about if my power supply is defective. But it is fine until I turn on VT-x. Is it some issue with CPU? I search through Google and didn't find anyone with my issue.

Comment: I have my PC installed hackintosh. But without VT-x, I cannot install any OS in virtualbox because the mac version of virtualbox requires VT-x in default. Such a pain..

Comment: Not sure. Could be the CPU or the motherboard. I don't think it could actually have anything to do with the PSU. It's just the issue could be a "model-wide" defect instead of the pieces you got.